# Convert cURL command into pure Java

Tags: java, http, url, post, curl

I have got a google token and with it, I request an authentication URL from google with the following cURL command:

```
curl --data 'accountType=&Email=&has_permission=1&Token= + $$TOKEN$$ + &service=weblogin%3Acontinue%3Dhttps%253A//www.google.com/dashboard/&source=&androidId=&app=&client_sig=&device_country=&operatorCountry=&lang=&RefreshServices=' -k 'https://android.clients.google.com/auth'
```

How can I convert this command into a pure java command with URL connections or the Apache HTTP library? So that I don't have to use the cURL binary any more.

I saw several examples but I'm facing some troubles with the POST parameters. I can't get is right.

**My java try:**

$$ TOKEN $$ --> must be replaced by the real token.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

public class Test implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        Thread thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost("https://android.clients.google.com/auth");

        try {

          List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
          nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("accountType", ""));
          nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Email", ""));
          nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("has_permission", "1"));
          nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Token", "$$ TOKEN $$"));
          nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("service", "weblogin%3Acontinue%3Dhttps%253A//www.google.com/dashboard/"));
          nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("androidId", ""));
          nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("app", ""));
          nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client_sig", ""));
          nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("device_country", ""));
          nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("operatorCountry", ""));
          nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lang", ""));
          nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("RefreshServices", ""));

          post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
          HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
          BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

          String line = "";
          while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);

          }
        } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**My eclipse console prints:**

```
Url=https://www.google.com/accounts/ErrorMsg?id=unknown
Error=Unknown
```

---

**SOLUTION:**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;

import javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSession;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;

public class Test implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        Thread thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        String data;
        String selectedToken = "xxx YOUR TOKEN HERE xxx";

        try {
            data = "accountType=&Email=&has_permission=1&Token=" + selectedToken +
                    "&service=weblogin%3Acontinue%3Dhttps%253A//www.google.com/dashboard/&source=&androidId=" +
                    "&app=&client_sig=&device_country=&operatorCountry=&lang=&RefreshServices=";

            // Disable cert validation
            disableCertificateValidation();

            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) new URL("https://android.clients.google.com/auth").openConnection();
            con.setRequestMethod("POST");
            con.setDoOutput(true);
            con.getOutputStream().write(data.getBytes("UTF-8"));

            // Get the inputstream
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

            // .. and print it
            String tmp;
            while((tmp = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(tmp);
            }
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void disableCertificateValidation() {
        // Create a trust manager that does not validate certificate chains
        TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] { new X509TrustManager() {
            public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() { 
                return new X509Certificate[0]; 
            }

            @Override
            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {

            }

            @Override
            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {

            }
        }};

        // Ignore differences between given hostname and certificate hostname
        HostnameVerifier hv = new HostnameVerifier() {
            @Override
            public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                return true;
            }
        };

        // Install the all-trusting trust manager
        try {
            SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
            sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new SecureRandom());
            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(hv);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Do nothing
        }
    }
}
```

I just had to add the SSL cert validation and then it worked.

Comment: post your code and the error please

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using an OAuth library to handle all this?

Comment: I edited it into the first post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use java.net.HttpURLConnection you can write the bytes of the post data right to the outputstream.  So all you would have to do is take your --data and convert it to bytes and write it to the stream.

Comment: I get a "javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException" and a "java.security.cert.CertificateException". How can I bypass the SSL cert check - like the "-k" option of cURL does?

Comment: Your answer would work like a charme if the target URL is http. If the site has SSL, you need to add a ssl cert validation (see code in my first post) - then it works perfectly. Thanks ;)